# Docking/floating with MFC ribbon

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon, ribbon-control

When using the MFC ribbon (as described [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/06/06/ribbon-with-c-part-2-first-ribbon-enabled-application/)), is it possible to create a ribbon that the user can move around to dock elsewhere around the window, or float?

Comment: The first thing I would like to mention is that ribbon on the linked page is  Windows Ribbon Framework, not MFC ribbon. You can certainly make a separate tool window with ribbon, but that would be inconsistent with other ribbon applications. Docking it anywhere except top part of the window makes little sense as well.

Comment: @VTT you should post this as answer, seems like a perfect answer to me.

Comment: Hm, would re-think about using the ribbon at all. At least as far as my personal experience goes (admitted, the sample is too small to be representative), the majority of people hate it and just use it because of being forced to - even after ribbons reaching ten years of age now... Would be curious if there are official statistics?